# output as.logical with print in R studio

Tags: r

```
x <- c("a",1, 3>2)
print(as.logical(x))
```

How does this give an answer as `Na` `Na` `TRUE`?

If individually we check then

```
as.logical('a')
[1] NA
as.logical(1)
[1] TRUE
as.logical(3>2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you investigate `X`, you will find that it is of type `character`.

```
> str(x)
 chr [1:3] "a" "1" "TRUE"
```

Now the definition of the `as.logical` function describes as:

`as.logical` attempts to coerce its argument to be of logical type. Character strings `c("T", "TRUE", "True", "true")` are regarded as `true`, `c("F", "FALSE", "False", "false")` as `false`, and `all others as NA`.

Its very clear from above rules that "a" and "1" will coerce to `NA`. Hence output of `print(as.logical(x))` as `Na Na TRUE` is valid and justified.

Comment: @sr_sr you are welcome. You can accept the answer by clicking  on `tick` in left side of the answer box.